# Understanding the fourth requirement for Power BI to mark a date table

Tags: powerbi

**See answer from Alexis it also applies for SSAS (Analysis services)**

From MI docs [set and use date tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-date-tables#setting-your-own-date-table). Fourth requirement to do so:

[image]

How should we interpret that?

Example of not working code,

```
CALENDAR = CROSSJOIN ( CALENDARAUTO( 12 ) , GENERATESERIES ( 0, 23, 1 ) )
```

Another column:

```
utc-0 = 'CALENDAR'[date utc-0] + TIME( [hour utc-0], 0, 0 )
```

[image]

Values are unique and correlative. It follows that I must be violating the fourth rule.

[image]

Comment: So, what's the question?

Comment: The sentence ending with a question mark, is the question @Olly

Comment: I don't think it could be any clearer. Each value in the column must have the same timestamp.

Comment: The date table is literally to generate seperate days. If you add timestamps for each hour, minute and second you would get a dataset that is too big to use. If you would like time as dimension, you should make a separate timetable.

Comment: @Olly I don't understand it, so please, teach me.

Comment: @Max, that's what I thought. A Power BI limitation, I'd say. Thanks.

Comment: I indeed believe that would be the case. Imagine waiting 10mins for your query to process only to find out your measure is wrong. :'(

Comment: Now that I think about it, it is also because you select a column as a datetable, which means you will connect facttables to the date dimension table, this needs to be a many-to-one relationship.

Comment: @Max I'll accept you an answer if you put it more formally, in answers.

Comment: It is named "DATE TABLE", not "DATETIME TABLE". The dates there must be unique. The same time part in case of datetime type means "zero time, i.e. midnights, somewhere in the world", which is kinda the same as a date without time.

Comment: @SNR I don't have the time right now to work it out good enough so that it is usable for other users in the future, sorry!

Comment: This is bad practice, have separate date and time tables, it will introduce complication to you relationships and query and dax formula and query engine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for a **date table** to qualify as a date table (rather than a datetime table), it can only have one row per day. The last requirement says that if the date column uses a date/time data type, then the time component of the datetime must be the same across every row of the date table (e.g. not 7 AM one day and 8 AM another day).

This is more of a design choice rather than a "Power BI limitation". If you want to analyze your data with respect to date *and* time, in addition to your date dimension table, you should create a separate time dimension table. Trying to do both in the same table isn't usually a good idea.

See here for a bit more detail on this:

https://radacad.com/how-to-use-time-and-date-dimensions-in-a-power-bi-model

Comment: Does that hold also for SSAS (Analysis Services)?

Comment: Which part are you referring to?

Comment: I listened more than once, Power BI being referred as an instance of `SSAS` and I do believe that's true, however I didn't know that this had several parts.

Comment: Power BI is indeed SSAS tabular under the hood. I was asking what part of my answer you were referring to.

Comment: To mark a datetime table as a date table.

Comment: ["The datetime column in the date table should be at day granularity (without fractions of a day)."](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/tabular-models/specify-mark-as-date-table-for-use-with-time-intelligence-ssas-tabular)

Comment: That's what I've thought was to follow. Wow that was a fine piece of work. I upvoted the question, not just for the question per se, but for the references given with it.

Answer (score 0):

Every row of the "date" column of your date table must contain a unique date value.

If this column is formatted as datetime, then the time value of every row must be identical.